# JQM Remove an element upon form select value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a single conditional form element in my first JQM site

in essence I want to add a field if the value of a previously selected meets a predefined constant.

```
<select id="list1">
    <option value="1">Item1</option>
    <option value="2">Item2</option>
</select>
<select id="list2">
    <option value="3">Item3</option>
    <option value="4">Item4</option>
</select>
```

Using JQM, I would like to dynamically remove `list2` if option value 2 is selected from `list1`

I am certain that this is a newb question... but thats exactly what I am.  Any help / advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#list1').on('change', function () {
 if ($(this).val() == '2') {
  $('#list2').parent('div').hide();
 } else {
    $('#list2').parent('div').show();
 }
});
```

Example: [Show/Hide select menu](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/Jv3mv/)

Comment: Many Thanks, tried to vote up, but sadly I dont hae enough rep.

Comment: I will, but I sadly missed an even more obvious point... how would i 'recover' the element should the user change back to option value 1?